# Migrate clickhouse DB to new server

Tags: clickhouse

I have one DB on a clickhouse-server. I want to migrate it to a new clickhouse server. How to do it correctly? I tried using clickhouse-backup, but got errors

```
2021/05/31 15:21:45  warn can't create table 'Data.Calls': <nil>, will try again
2021/05/31 15:21:45  warn can't create table 'Data.Fcst_1': <nil>, will try again
2021/05/31 15:21:45  warn can't create table 'Data.Fcst_3': <nil>, will try again
2021/05/31 15:21:45  warn can't create table 'Data.GAInfo': <nil>, will try again
2021/05/31 15:21:45  warn can't create table 'Data.HistoryLogs': <nil>, will try again
2021/05/31 15:21:45  warn can't create table 'Data.Info': <nil>, will try again
2021/05/31 15:21:45  warn can't create table 'Data.Info1': <nil>, will try again
2021/05/31 15:21:45  warn can't create table 'Data.Info15': <nil>, will try again
2021/05/31 15:21:45  warn can't create table 'Data.Info548': <nil>, will try again
2021/05/31 15:21:45  warn can't create table 'Data.Info60': <nil>, will try again
2021/05/31 15:21:45  warn can't create table 'Data.InfoAXPNew': <nil>, will try again
2021/05/31 15:21:45  warn can't create table 'Data.InfoAXPOld': <nil>, will try again
2021/05/31 15:21:45  warn can't create table 'Data.InfoPageView': <nil>, will try again
```

Comment: try the latest version of clickhouse-backup

Comment: You can simply RSYNC /var/lib/clickhouse

Answer (score 0):

It depends on connectivity between old and new clusters.

It it is present (and good), you can try [remote](https://www.google.com/amp/s/clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/table-functions/remote/amp/) function which is the most flexible way to migrate.

I would further suggest to write a script which can read table using `remote` function and create table on new cluster and then inserts data either in one go or `daily`, `weekly` or `monthly` iteration with `WHERE somedatecolumn BETWEEN {start_date} AND {end_date}`.

And if you cannot establish direct connectivity between old and new clusters, you will have to fall back to conventional ways of data extraction and upload.